# VB.Net Save button not adding data to text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-debugging

I'm still new to VB.Net and have been stuck on this for a little over an  hour. I'm trying to create an inventory management system where a form opens up for the user to enter pc specs and when I click save will save to the text file, so that it is read into the Inventory Tracker screen. Where each text box is disabled and appends the text as it is updated.

Currently nothing is happening, I've created the text file in the same directory as the project. Why is this?

I also tried putting a test message in the text file to display in the tracker text box, which is what will happen when I save the specs, however no message is appearing?

frmItemEntry.vb

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim objMyStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim objMyStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("inventory.txt")

    Dim strInventory As String

    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtManufacturerEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtProcessorEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtVideoEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtFormEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtRamEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtVramEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(txtHdEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.WriteLine(chkWirelessEntry)
    objMyStreamWriter.Close()

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

frmTracker.vb

```
Private Sub txtManufacturer_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtManufacturer.TextChanged
    Dim streamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("inventory.txt")
    Dim strInventory As String
    streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("inventory.txt")
    strInventory = streamReader.ReadLine
    txtManufacturer.AppendText(strInventory)
End Sub
```

Comment: what debugging have you done? Have you stepped through the code line by line to see what is happening and what the variable values are at that time? Are your event handlers definitely running? Are you getting any errors or exceptions? If the best you can say to us is "nothing happens" then generally it means you haven't yet investigated the issue fully.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, and the 2 warnings would be for frmItemEntry.vb where the variables objMyStreamReader and strInventory are unused local variables, however they are not used due to just writing the lines to the text file.

Comment: Ok. And what happens when you step through the code line by line with the debugger, as I mentioned? Does it execute the lines you want it to? Are all the variables holding the values you expect?

Comment: I've tried to go through it with the debugger and the Immediate Window remains blank.

Comment: Since (in step-through mode) it stops on every line you can see precisely which lines of code are being executed, and then you can hover over the variables to see what values are contained within them. I didn't ask you to do anything with the Immediate window. If you don't understand how to use the VS debugger, please [take a moment to learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017) before continuing. This is a vital skill you'll need in order to succeed with writing .NET applications.

Comment: P.S. the [immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2017) has a different purpose - you have to actively type commands into it in order to get responses. It does not automatically get filled by output from the debugger.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are expecting to happen that _doesn't_ happen? Currently you are doing three things: 1) Writing data to a file, 2) Reading data from that file, and 3) Outputting said data in your application - Which one of these is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. When mousing over the variable it displays the text "TEST" which would be accurate. However, it's just not writing to the text file. Which is my main issue currently, the  text file just remains blank.

Comment: "the variable" ...which variable? You're trying to write lots of variables into your file, from what I can see. Please give us clear, specific, accurate and detailed info. On the face of it, there's not much, if anything, wrong with your code, so there's obviously some background detail which is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, every variable showed the correct text through the debugger. They are just not saving / updating the text file.

Comment: Are you definitely looking at the right file? When you build and run a .NET project in VS it compiles the code into binary format in a sub-folder under your project (normally `bin\Debug` in you're in Debug mode) and also copies all the associated artefacts there, such as text files - similar to if you were deploying the final executable to the place where it will run for real. This becomes the root directory for the program while it's running. I suggest checking if it's actually updating a copy of the file in _that_ sub-directory, not in the folder where your source code lives.

Comment: P.S. as a broader point, if you're serious about creating a useful inventory management system, you'd be far better storing your data in a small database rather than in text files. It will be much easier to manage multiple entries and also run queries to get statistics about your data.

Comment: @ADyson you were right, The file was in bin\Debug. The lines are outputted such as "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Dell". How do I go about only having the output as "Dell"?

Comment: You'd do that by saving only the [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the textbox into the file, not the entire textbox object. A textbox [consists of a lot more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) than just the text written in the box!

Comment: You should be using `txtManufacturerEntry.Text` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you definitely looking at the right file?

When you build and run a .NET project in VS it compiles the code into a sub-folder under your project (normally `bin\Debug` in you're in Debug mode) and also copies all the associated artefacts there, such as text files - similar to if you were deploying the final executable to the place where it will run for real. This becomes the root directory for the program while it's running.

I would expect that it's actually updating a copy of the file in that sub-directory, not in the folder where your source code lives.

Comment: As a quick follow up, what change could I make to the line "Dim objMyStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("inventory.txt")" to update the current text file with additional entries rather than clearing the whole file.

Comment: @Devin I don't want to sound mean but that is really quite a common and trivial requirement which you can [google easily](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=zlNIXMLaE9CvkwWR1YeYDw&q=vb.net+open+text+file+and+add+new+lines&oq=vb.net+open+text+file+and+add+new+lines&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30l2.125142.127961..128077...0.0..0.275.2170.0j7j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i22i30.GH-0MzkNGQY). I'd like to think that don't need me (or anyone else) to go and look it up on your behalf. As you'll see you're far from the first person to want to do that...